Concatenating two dataframes causes column header of index to disappear
I have two dataframes df_old and df_new.
df_old has a date column and a bunch of other columns. df_new has ONLY a date column, which is also set as its index.
The dates in df_new are a superset of df_old
I want to concatenate the data frames, such that the columns of df_old line up with the dates in df_new, and any column that doesn't line up will have Nan.
df_new = pd.DataFrame()
df_new["date"] = pd.date_range(start='31/12/2023', end='31/12/2024')
df_new.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df_new = pd.concat([df_new , df_old], join="outer")

after doing this, however, the 'date' column name of df_new is now an empty string.
Any advice here? I tried renaming the column by index reference [0] but no joy
Thanks in advance

Please provide a sample of df_old using df_old.head().to_dict()

"df_new has ONLY a date column, which is also set as its index." so you almost have an Index (actually an DataFrame without columns).
Thus you should rather reindex:
out = df_old.reindex(df_new.index)

Given your example of df_old, it looks like "date" is the column axis name.
You could either keep it and remove the index name:
out = df_old.reindex(df_new.index.rename(None))

Or remove it:
out = df_old.reindex(df_new.index).rename_axis(columns=None)

Or both:
out = df_old.reindex(df_new.index).rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)

Or move it back to column:
out = df_old.reindex(df_new.index).rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()


I tried removing the set_index line completely, but i don't get a join like that. I need df_old to be indexed on date as I'm transposing it earlier in the process. I don't quite follow how reindexing would work here? do you mind elaborating?

PROGRESS! just to say - i tried using reindexing rather than concat, and it seems to work...however....my new column is now called date date (with the second date apparently on a new line below the first)! Why?!

Can you provide the output of df_old.head().to_dict('tight') to better understand the issue? (please edit your question)

{'index': [datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 31, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 31, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2024, 2, 29, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2024, 3, 31, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 30, 0, 0)], 'columns': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'], 'data': [[13.0, 77, 22 34, 78, 0.0, 13.2, 0.0, 0.0], ......., 'index_names': [None], 'column_names': ['date']}

I see, this is not a column but the index name. Your df_old DataFrame has "date" as column Index name. See update

yeah i need df_old to have date as an index because i transpose it earlier in the process. is there a way to convert it back into a column from an index after the transpose operation?

Yes, add reset_index(). See my last update
